# IOS memory warning Level 2

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, instruments

[image]Screen-shot from instruments

The overall memory usage increases in my iOS application but living bytes remain constant. But application crashes once the overall memory usage crosses 150 MB, with memory warning Level 2. The living bytes is within 6 MB. I don't have any other app running in the iPod touch.

While using instruments which section we need to see to get information about memory usage. There is no memory leaks in this app.

What could be the reason for memory warning level 2, when living bytes is within 6 MB ?

Comment: OMG..Have you released any allocated object in your app? Please check where you are getting the leaks.. If you dont know how you can detect the places where your memory is leaking then you can refer to Apple's WWDC Session Videos. Hope this would help you out.

Comment: This could be caused by application trying to allocate a lot of memory at once (20-30MB maybe?). Is your app passes through same code in the beginning without warning? If so, then there's something unreleased that piles up in memory. Also - make sure you're viewing ALL allocations. Not only the ones with CF and NS prefixes.

Comment: @Eimantas I have made sure that there is no memory leak in the app. You can see living bytes in the screen-shot.

Comment: Living bytes may not reflect the amount of memory about to be allocated. If app *tries* to take a lot of memory it will get killed (e.g. if it tries to take more than there is free memory at all).

Comment: Any chance you have NSZombiesEnabled=YES?

Comment: As always, don't trust the Object Allocations instrument to give you the total memory size of your application.  Use the Memory Monitor instrument for a more accurate read of the total application size.  It will be much larger than the 6 MB you point out here.  Odds are that it's large enough to start hitting system limits on memory usage.

Comment: @BradLarson There was an Object which was getting allocated continuously and never got released. Instruments was not showing that in allocated or leaking bytes.

Comment: @sach - That may not have been a leak in the traditional sense, but there still are ways of tracking these down, as Bill Bumgarner points out here: http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/